# Like Box Shows Error for liking blog page, but articles work fine

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, meta-tags

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now. I have a simple wordpress blog. I've plugged in all the OG meta tags and run the page though the debugger many times and it shows no errors.

However when people click the Like button (generated from the Like Box plugin), they get the red error message suggesting that the page be run through the debugger.

I have generated other like buttons that live on individual blog posts, and so far these seem to be working fine, its only when trying to like page there is an issue.

Also note, that the facebook page was generated from the OG meta data after I had liked it. So this isn't from creating a page in Facebook and then trying to have people like it. I mention that just in case it matters.

The other thing of note, is that if I am already logged in (just me the admin), I can like and unlike it with no errors. If however I log out of facebook, and click the like button, after entering my facebook login, I see the error just as other users have.

I've been reading forum posts for days and have yet to find a solution. My blog URL is http://www.garrinball.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your http://www.garrinball.com/ parses just fine on the linter.  However, this is only a small issue, you don't specify any og:image tag on http://www.garrinball.com/2011/10/christmas-card-shoot/.

What is strange is I don't see any errors.  I like the christmas-card-shoot and the like button maintained my like even after page refresh.

I also logged out of facebook, went back to like it, and it prompted me for credentials as normal.  I logged in, and was able to like the button. No errors.

I'm wondering if it is specific to your account you're using.

Comment: I ended up deleting the facebook page, and re-creating it by liking it again on my site. This at least refreshed all the data that wouldn't seem to refresh. However the facebook like-box still would give errors. However the regular like button seems to work. I'm wondering if the like box doesn't play real nice with pages created via the open graph? Or maybe there is something I'm missing. I just have a feeling if I had created a page via facebook directly, then used the like-box it would be working.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying with an other fb account.

I have a fanpage tab application with a like button on it, and after a while testing I got the exact same error as you :

[image: Error after liking]

```
    <!-- with the JS SDK included and inited -->
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="//fanpage-url" data-send="false" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

When refreshing, the like button is however detecting correctly the like status.

No error message shows up when using another account than my admin-dev one... maybe its an antispam function ?